# How to fetch (see) GUIDs of a FORM and VIEW of an entity in MS CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

any idea on "how to fetch (see) GUIDs of a FORM and VIEW of an entity in MS CRM?" using WEB API Call?

Answer (score 0):

Referring [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607589.aspx), you can use the following snippet to query CRM Form. `Objecttypecode` will be the entity to filter.

```
[organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/systemforms
```

[For view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607533.aspx):

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/savedqueries?$select=name,savedqueryid&$filter=name eq 'Active Accounts'
```